# postfix multi instance transport

Tags: postfix

I'm configuring a postfix mailing server with multiple instances. 
Each instance has been assigned it's own ip and domain.
For some of the instances, I've enabled rate delays for specific domains:

main.cf

```
yahoo_destination_rate_delay = 5s
yahoo_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 10
yahoo_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
ymail_destination_rate_delay = 5s
ymail_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 10
ymail_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
```

master.cf

```
yahoo      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix-3
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
ymail      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    -o syslog_name=postfix-3
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=
```

transport

```
yahoo.com    yahoo:
ymail.com    ymail:
```

My question is, how does each instance know which transport to use? i set

```
postmap /etc/postfix-3/transport
```

but is that enough?

It seems to be working but that could only be because a few other instances have similar transports. I'm afraid each instance could be reading an incorrect transport map. Should I assign each instance a specific transport file or is that assumed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to answer my question:

Mail transport switch

Once the trivial-rewrite(8) daemon has determined a default delivery method it searches the optional transport(5) table for information that overrides the message destination and/or delivery method. Typical use of the transport(5) table is to send mail to a system that is not connected to the Internet, or to use a special SMTP client configuration for destinations that have special requirements. See, for example, the STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README and UUCP_README documents, and the examples in the transport(5) manual page.

***Transport table lookups are disabled by default***. To enable, edit the transport_maps parameter in the main.cf file and specify one or more lookup tables, separated by whitespace or commas.

Example:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
/etc/postfix-3/main.cf:
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix-3/transport
```

I simply edited each instances main.cf and added the transport_maps option and pointed to the correct transport map. All seems to work ok.

source: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean. Each instance has it's own folder under `/etc/` and you have transports configured in each `master.cf` in each instance folder.

All instances are independent of each other and don't know each others configuration. Except the few configuration parameters that configure the instances itself.